# Place a character in empty div-s with a specified class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="display_label">Work phone:</div>
<div class="display_work_phone display_attr"></div>

<div class="display_label">Email:</div>
<div class="display_work_phone display_attr"></div>

<div class="display_label">Comment:</div>
<div class="display_comment display_attr"></div>
```

Probably, Work Phone and Comment is gonna be empty sometimes, so I'd like to replace that "emptiness" with a "-" character. I tried to check if its length is 0, but I couldn't figure it out how to make it work. I'd like to check and replace every div's content with classname "display_attr" if it has no value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [:empty-selector](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)

```
$('.display_work_phone, .display_comment').filter(':empty').html('-')
```

Note: If the node contains a empty text node then the empty selector won't work, in such case you can write a simple filter yourself like

```
$('.display_work_phone, .display_comment').filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).text()).length == 0
}).html('-')
```

Comment: What if the div has spaces as a content ?

Comment: less chars .. `return /^\s*$/.test($(this).text())`  `;)`

Answer (score 2):

You could also use css:

```
.display_attr:empty::after { content: '-'; }
```

But it does not work if the element contains spaces.

**Browser-Support:**

- [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aafter) (IE8+)
- [:empty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aempty) (IE9+)

Comment: Browsers support ? `:/`

Comment: IE 8 do not support `:empty` selector `:(` Otherwise it would have been the best choice to me.

Comment: This solution worked fine as well, thank you. Except the annonying IE lol

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would handle this issue ..

```
$('.display_work_phone, .display_comment').filter(function () {
    return /^\s*$/.test($(this).text());
}).html('-');
```